# Phalcon PHP still going to default template even after view->pick

Tags: php, twig, phalcon, volt

Hello guys i have a basic class like this

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{


    public function onConstruct(){

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        return $this->view->pick(array("login/login"));         
    }   

}
```

I want it to render whats there in the login folder and login.volt

Thing is, it is rendering it , but also it is rendering what is there in index.volt and which has the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Phalcon PHP Framework</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ content() }}
    </body>
</html>
```

So im getting double html double bodys etc

Can someone tell me why this is happening and/or suggest a fix. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Try to use setMainView method

```
class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{


    public function onConstruct(){

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {

        return $this->view->setMainView("login/login");         
    }   

}
```

setMainView method use to set the default view. Just put the view name as parameter.
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` keyword. I believe it is fetching the view you want and then returning it into the base template.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way to use view in phalcon

```
$this->view->pick(array('login/login')); // with  layout 

$this->view->pick('login/login'); // without layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set action view only by `setRenderLevel`

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->setRenderLevel(View::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
    return $this->view->pick(array("login/login"));         
}
```